# How to show table rows after they've been hidden

Tags: jquery, performance, html-table

I have a large table and allow the user to hide rows based upon a lot of complicated rules.
I also have a 'reset' button that is to reveal all the rows back again, but it is running very slowly:

```
$('#myTable tbody tr').show('fast');
```

Q: Is there a fast way to show table rows that have been previously hidden with the hide method?

Perhaps I should add class="hide" and removeClass instead.

Comment: `$('#myTable tbody tr').show(0);` -- 0 = instant.

Comment: The problem is it's looping over all the thousands of rows.

Comment: So what your telling me is that the CPU usage is ridiculous and you're wondering if there's a workaround for animating thousands of elements at the same time without suffering the drain on the processing?

Comment: I never know what clever thing people come up with in JavaScript, like removing it from the DOM, looping over it and adding it back.

Comment: Why not `$('#myTable tbody').show('fast')`?

Comment: I predict toggling (hide/show) would be more processor friendly than removing rows and regenerating them, which internally probably does the same hide and show anyway but alleviates the need to...regenerate the rows.  If instant-hide/show doesn't work, you should wonder if the user needs that many rows at once in the first place. (in other words, server side rather than client side)

Comment: undefined: I tried that per your suggestion.  It's the rows that are hidden, not the tbody.  So showing the tbody didn't do anything.

Comment: The best way to do this is just to add / remove class just as you expect. The problem with `show/hide` is that they leverage `$.fx.step` which occurs `once every 17 milliseconds.` If you have `1000` rows, that's `1000 operations every 17 milliseconds` which will undoubtedly hang most browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want to show the ones that are hidden, not the whole set, also if the `tr`'s are direct childs of `tbody` is faster to use the child selector, so try this:

```
$('#myTable tbody > tr:hidden').show('fast');
```

if after trying that, it's still slow for you, you could try with the [viewport plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport) to only animate those that are actually shown in screen, like so:

```
$('#myTable tbody > tr:hidden').filter(":in-viewport").show('fast', function() {
   $('#myTable tbody > tr:hidden').show();//show rest tr's that are out of viewport
});
```

**UPDATE:**
Updated to add direct child selectors.

Comment: Wow.  That's what I'm talking about when it comes to people having solutions that I never would have thought of.